# C# bulk insert to sql, but table is empty

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to insert bulk data from my data table, but after an execution of the table in my database it's still empty when I test query to see if the data were written.

Below is my code for inserting from data table to sql:

```
private void btnToSql_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //First create a connection string to destination database
            string connectionString;
            connectionString = @"MY DATA STRING - I REPLACED IT JUST TO POST HERE";

            //Open a connection with destination database;
            using (SqlConnection connection =
                   new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                //Open bulkcopy connection.
                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
                {
                    //Set destination table name
                    //to table previously created.
                    bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Table_1";

                    try
                    {
                        bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelRecords);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }

                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Finished!");
    }
```

Here is how I create/populate my data table (data table is declared globally):

```
 public void importExcel(string path, string sheetName)
    {
        var excel = new LinqToExcel.ExcelQueryFactory(path);
        excel.ReadOnly = true;
        var companies = from a in excel.Worksheet(sheetName) select a;
        var columnNames = excel.GetColumnNames(sheetName);


        foreach (var columnName in columnNames)
        {
            dtExcelRecords.Columns.Add(columnName);
        }
        foreach (var row in companies)
        {
            DataRow dr = dtExcelRecords.NewRow();
            foreach (var columnName in columnNames)
            {
                dr[columnName] = row[columnName];
            }
            dtExcelRecords.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dtExcelRecords;
    }
```

Comment: Your posted code doesn't show how `dtExcelRecords` gets created or populated.   Maybe it's empty.

Comment: Its definitelly not empty because i display it in a dataGridView and the whole data from excel shows up

Comment: i edited my post and added the code how i populate it tho

Comment: But what about order of operations?  Maybe it's empty when your code hits the `WriteToServer` line.  Have you paused in the debugger and viewed it?

Comment: I just did that, and there are 23columns and 483 rows... so its full, no?

Comment: Sounds that way.  In that case I have no idea what is going wrong.

Comment: Maybe you are writing against another server? Or another table? A while ago somebody had a similiar and strange problem. The reason was an `INSTEAD OF TRIGGER` on the database... Check for triggers on your table... Do you know how to work with the profiler? Try to monitor which command reach the SQL Server. Try to insert data manually...

Comment: Do you get something in the console from the catch block? `catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);   }`

Comment: @Alexei oh, thanks, i didnt check for messages in the console, one of my columns didnt take enough spaces, thanks, i solved my issue now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my question and received answer in the comments area the problem seems to be related to exception silently caught in the block:

```
catch (Exception ex) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); 
}
```

My suggestion is to separate DB access logic (`DAL`) from your `UI`, by putting this logic in another class (usually it is put in another assembly) and have a pattern like this one:

**Data layer**

```
try
{
    // DB logic fetch
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    // log somewhere - NLog is one way to easily log to anything you want - console, DB, file - and also store important information such as timestamp, user, stack trace etc.
    // put error in some output variable or property
}
```

**UI layer**

- calls data layer
- if something fails, print a friendly answer for the user
- look in the logs for the actual error

This is an important separation of concerns and you can also have a good exception management.